# Copying a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I ***get()*** an multidimensional array and store it inside the **$products** variable.

I need to Make a copy of that array to create it into a new Webshop because the export provided by the API does not work so I have created this script to copy the data:

```
foreach ($products as $id => $product) {

    $copy = $products[$id];
    $createdProducts = $apiSkylux->products->create(
        array(
            'id' => $copy['id'],
            'createdAt' => $copy['createdAt'],
            'updatedAt' => $copy['updatedAt'],
            'isVisible' => $copy['isVisible'],
            'visibility' => $copy['visibility'],
            'data01' => $copy['data01'],
            'data02' => $copy['data02'],
            'data03' => $copy['data03'],
            'url' => $copy['url'],
            'title' => $copy['title'],
            'fulltitle' => $copy['fulltitle'],
            'description' => $copy['description'],
            'content' => $copy['content'],
            'set' => $copy['set'],
            'brand' => $copy['brand'],
            'categories' => $copy['categories'],
            'deliverydate' => $copy['deliverydate'],
            'image' => $copy['image'],
            'images' => $copy['images'],
            'relations' => $copy['relations'],
            'reviews' => $copy['reviews'],
            'type' => $copy['type'],
            'attributes' => $copy['attributes'],
            'supplier' => $copy['supplier'],
            'tags' => $copy['tags'],
            'variants' => $copy['variants'],
            'movements' => $copy['movements'],

        )
    );

}
```

The copy is working. But i thought *@2016* and all, can't this be achieved with less lines of code?

This is what I receive with `var_dump` of the first array:

```
var_dump($products[0]);
    exit;
//result
array(28) {
  ["id"]=>
   int(26136946)
//rest of array
```

So I can see the array has a number *(28)* , what does this represent?

I've tried several attempts, closest attempt was :

```
$copy = $products[$id];
            $createProducts = $products;
            $createdProducts = $apiSkylux->products->create($createProducts);
```

But then I also got an `error : Invalid data input`

Can I copy the data from the array easier then the method I am currently using?

Comment: `$apiSkylux->products->create($copy)` would do exactly the same thing as repeating every single key into a new array... Beyond this I'm not sure what `create()` is doing or not doing and why you need a "copy" in the first place.

Comment: 28 represents the count of elements the array has..

Comment: @deceze, can't believe sometimes I just don't see it , that simple. I need a Copy because the products that are in 1 webshop need to be copied to a new Webshop for replacement.

Comment: Inside your `foreach`, instead of `$copy` use `$product`

Comment: @CodeGodie yes! I started that $copy variable for less writing purposes. Could have been all reduced to $product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> array(
>     'id' => $copy['id'],
>     ...
> )
> ```

This can be reduced to simply:

```
$copy
```

Yes, reassigning every single key into a new array is the same as using the original array in the first place.

> ```
> foreach($products as $id => $product){
>     $copy = $products[$id];
> ```

This can be reduced to:

```
foreach ($products as $product){
    $copy = $product;
```

Obviously you could leave out `$copy` entirely and just use `$product`.

Bottom line:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $createdProducts = $apiSkylux->products->create($product);
}
```

What you do with `$createdProducts` I don't know; you don't seem to be doing anything with it inside the loop, so at best it'll hold the last product after the loop, so is probably superfluous.

Probably you could do:

```
array_map([$apiSkylux->products, 'create'], $products);
```

or

```
$createdProducts = array_map([$apiSkylux->products, 'create'], $products);
```

depending on whether you need the return values or not.

> So I can see the array has a number (28) , what does this represent?

It means it's an array with 28 elements in it.

Comment: Is it normal that I overlook something so simple? Really thought my question was valid and eventually it's such a simple solution. Thanks for the proper explanation. $createdProducts at the moment is not doing anything. I just wanted to make the copy and after the copy I can call the same products I did in the past webshop. can I just leave $createdProducts = .. out then actually?

Comment: Your self-assessment in your profile may be a bit optimistic yet... ;-P

Comment: If you're not using a variable, don't create it in the first place.

Comment: I Will decrease it all by 1 level now, :(.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make any sense. Simply use the `$product` variable within the loop. Done!